# Find limiting distribution of $(nb)^{-1/\alpha}X_{(n)}$ where $X_j$'s are i.i.d random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

Let $\{X_{j}:j \geq 1 \}$ be independent random variables  identically distributed with distribution function $F$ and $X_{(n)}=\max\{X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}\}$ . Let $\alpha >0$ be such that $\lim_{a \to \infty} a^{\alpha} P(X_{1}>a)=b$, with $b>0$. Find the limit distribution of $(nb)^{-1/\alpha}X_{(n)}$.

Image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZDua.png)

I have this:

Let be $t \in \mathbb R$, and, $Y_{n}=(nb)^{-1/\alpha}X_{(n)}$.

\begin{align}
P(Y_{n} \leq t)=P(X_{(n)}\leq t(nb)^{1/\alpha})&=P(\max\{X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}\} \leq t(nb)^{1/\alpha})
\\&=\prod_{i=1}^{n}P(X_{i}\leq t(nb)^{1/\alpha})
\end{align}

I do not know how to use my hypothesis to find the limit of distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following :
\begin{align*}
\prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb P[X_i\leq t(nb)^{1/\alpha}] &= \mathbb P[X_1\leq t(nb)^{1/\alpha}]^n\\
&= (1-\mathbb P[X_1> t(nb)^{1/\alpha}])^n\\
&= (1-\frac{1}{t^\alpha nb}\cdot t^\alpha nb\cdot \mathbb P[X_1> t(nb)^{1/\alpha}])^n\\
&= \left(1-f(n)\cdot\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}
\end{align*}
Where $f(n)\to \frac{1}{t^\alpha}$ as $n\to\infty$. This is known to converge to the same limit as $e^{-f(n)}$ which is $e^{-\frac{1}{t^\alpha}}$.

Comment: Do you take $f(n)=\dfrac{t^{\alpha}nb}{t^{\alpha}b}P[X_{i} > t(nb)^{-1/\alpha}]$ ? , due to my hipothesis the limit when n tends to infinite is $\dfrac{b}{t^{\alpha} b} =\dfrac{1}{t^{\alpha}} $?

Comment: yes, this is the one, observe that the limit of $t^\alpha nb P[...]$ is $b$. You also should be careful with which $t$ this reasoning is valid, for instance when $t=0$ or when $t<0$.

Comment: I have a correction $(t(nb)^{-1/\alpha})^{\alpha} \neq t^{\alpha}nb$, so I can not apply the limit of the hypothesis . You have that $(t(nb)^{-1/\alpha})^{\alpha}= t^{\alpha}(nb)^{-1}$

Comment: Right, that means you cannot use your hypothesis like that (and at all probably).